# Python pep8 warnings about indentation when using bracket strings and more than two lines

Tags: python, formatting, indentation, pep8

I was writing some code using argparse in Python and my IDE complained about certain line indentations, but not about others.

```py
# (1) no brackets around help string, three lines, doesn't complain
parser.add_argument("--serial", action="store_const", help="This explains "
                    "the command in more words than the other argument."
                    "Thats why it takes three lines.")
# (2) brackets around help string, two lines, doesnt complain
parser.add_argument("-c", "--cores", type=int, help=("This argument only"
                    "needs two lines to explain it"))
# (3) brackets around help string, three lines, complains
# continuation line under-indented for visual indent (in the last line)
parser.add_argument("--serial", action="store_const", help=("This explains "
                    "the command in more words than the other argument."
                    "Thats why it takes three lines."))
# (4) three lines with brackets, but indented up to help, doesnt complain
parser.add_argument("--serial", action="store_const", help=("This explains "
                                                            "the command ."
                                                            "with few words."))
```

This was confirmed using online pep8 checkers with standard line length of 79 characters. Why is only (3) rejected by the format checker?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, (2) falls under the same PEP 8 ruling as (3).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters It's not only in the IDE though (PyCharm), but other online checkers show the same behaviour.

Comment: Those online checkers, in all likelyhood, use the exact same tool.

Comment: E.g. `pep8online.com` [uses the `pep8` project](http://pep8online.com/about). I think PyCharm does too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you think it's a bug in not recognizing the mistake with two lines, or a false positive with 3 lines? I.e. what does PEP-8 recommend

Comment: `pep8` was renamed to `pycodestyle`, and the project has a number of E1[23]\d\* issues open; links to subgroups (to work around GitHub search limitations): [E121-E125](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/search?q=type%3Aissue+E121+OR+E122+OR+E123+OR+E124+OR+E125&state=open&type=Issues), [E126-E129](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/search?q=type%3Aissue+E126+OR+E127+OR+E128+OR+E129&state=open&type=Issues), [E131, E133](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/search?q=type%3Aissue+E131+OR+E133&state=open&type=Issues). 16 open issues dealing with indentation on logical lines between brackets.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: it's a bug to not report example #2 as a E12\* or  E13\* error.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: not sure you are making sense.